# Como filtrar com ANGULAR JS para não repetir nomes iguais?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, framework

Eu tenho 2 tabelas relacionadas no banco: A primeira Tabela: se chama restaurante a outra Tabela : Cardapio . A Tabela Cardapio recebe a chave primaria de restaurante sendo assim se torna estrangeira até ai tudo certo, pego essa informação do banco com uma Api Php + Mysql faço o inner Join das 2 tabelas e me retorna um Json : Ai eu pego esses dados com meu Controller Angular Js e jogo para minha view aonde uso o Ng-repeat até tudo certo ele lista os nomes de Restaurantes só que infelizmente repete os nomes. Exemplo Tenho um Restaurante no Banco com Nome de BABYS Gula se eu ir a tabela cardápio e cadastrar 3 lanches para esse restaurante o nome desse Restaurante na minha Lista repete 3 vezes e se repete para os de mais restaurantes cadastrados .[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpgVL.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Diego Augusto já tentei nem com isso funcionou alguém me disse que eu tinha que fazer um filtro no Controller em Js mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso mas no ng-repeat já tentei de quase todos filtros do Js que poderia tentar ....

Comment: Estou montando uma resposta e um exemplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) para resolver esse problema.

Exemplo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.names = [{
    id: 1,
    Name: 'Diego'
}, {
    id: 2,
    Name: 'Bruno'
}, {
    id: 3,
    Name: 'Diego'
}]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in names | unique: 'Name' ">
    <li>{{item.Name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Repare que depois de instalar a lib é só utilizar o filtro `unique` no seu `ng-repeat` e escolher qual campo deve ser único:

```
ng-repeat="item in names | unique: 'Name'
```

Comment: DiegoAugusto muito obrigado vou tentar essa solução qualquer coisa volto aqui irmão abraços . Valeu mesmo

Comment: DiegoAugusto Valeu irmão deu certo já está resolvido ....Muito obrigado pela solução apliquei e deu certo abraços irmão Deus abençoe.

Comment: @Dan100 Por nada :D, se a resposta resolveru seu problema vc pode marca-la como solução.

Comment: Valeu mano vou marcar sim .... Thanks